# GridSearchCV best_score_ is nan when using StratifiedGroupKFold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

ever since switching my kfold from StratifiedKFold to StratifiedGroupKFold I have the issue that grid.best_score returns nan, while it worked fine before. My code looks like this:

```
kfold = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

train_indx, test_indx = next(GroupShuffleSplit(random_state=i, test_size=0.2).split(X, Y, groups))

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = X[train_indx], X[test_indx], Y[train_indx], Y[test_indx]


grid = GridSearchCV(clf, par, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(str(clf).split('(', 1)[0], "// Best Validation Score: {:.5f}".format(grid.best_score_), "// Test Score: {:.5f}".format(accuracy_score(Y_test, grid.best_estimator_.predict(X_test))))
```

returns something like:

```
LogisticRegression // Best Validation Score: nan // Test Score: 0.56164
```

Answer (score 1):

To have correct results [StratifiedGroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html) may expects `groups` to be specified. But you do not provide groups. You can pass the groups using two ways:

1. When calling `grid.fit`:

```
grid.fit(X_train, Y_train, groups=groups)
```

2. Or pass the iterable of (train, val) indices as a splitter:

```py
kfold = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0).split(X_train, y_train, groups=groups)
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, par, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I was able to solve the issue thanks to the first solution using groups=groups[train_indx]